# How to export objects with WBlock method to the origin point of the new drawing

Tags: c#, autocad

I need to export some objects selected by the user. This first part it's done, but now I need to place the objects exported at the origin point of the new drawing without opening this drawing. The minimal extent point of the objects selected need to be at the origin point.

I didn't find how to select the objects on the external model space and how to move them to the origin point.

```
// Create a new external database, where the
// exported objects will be created.
using (var newDb = new Database(true, false))
{    
    // objIds is an array of obejcts selected
    // by the user.
    db.Wblock(newDb, objIds, Point3d.Origin,
                                DuplicateRecordCloning.Ignore);
    newDb.SaveAs(MyFileName, DwgVersion.Newest);
}

// Here it's what I've tried: Open the 
// drawing with the ReadDWgFile method
// and to select all objects from model space,
// but no success.
using (var exDb = new Database(false, false))
{
        try
        {
            exDb.ReadDwgFile(MyFileName,
            FileOpenMode.OpenForReadAndWriteNoShare, false, "");
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            ed.WriteMessage("\nUnable to read drawing file.");
        }

        using (var exTr = exDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            // Open the Block table record for read
            BlockTable exBlkTbl;
            exBlkTbl = exTr.GetObject(exDb.BlockTableId,
                                      OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;

            // Open the Block table record Model space for read
            BlockTableRecord exBlkTblRec;
            exBlkTblRec = exTr.GetObject(exBlkTbl[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace],
               OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTableRecord;

            // Here I don't know how to proceed to 
            // get the objects from the model space
            // and then move to the origin point.
        }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, once I didn't find a way to modify the external database I found a solution in a different way. First, I move the selected objects to the origin point of the current drawing inside a transaction. Then, exports using the `wblock` method supplying the origin point as the `BasePoint` argument, and finally dispose the first transaction without commit, with this the objects still in your original point  the current drawing.

**By the way, a better solution is welcome.**

```
using (var trMoveToOrigin = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{
// Get the extents points 
// of the selected objects.
var extPts = trMoveToOrigin.GetExtents(objIdArray);
var minExPt = extPts.MinPoint;

// Get vector from minimal extent point
// to the origin point, that will be
// used to move the selected objects.
Vector3d acVec3d = minExPt.GetVectorTo(Point3d.Origin);

foreach (ObjectId objId in objIds)
{
    Entity e = trMoveToOrigin.GetObject(objId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as Entity;
    e.TransformBy(Matrix3d.Displacement(acVec3d));
}

// Create a new external database, where the
// exported objects will be created.
using (var newDb = new Database(true, false))
{
    using (var trExport = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
    {
        db.Wblock(newDb, objIds, Point3d.Origin,
                            DuplicateRecordCloning.Ignore);
        newDb.SaveAs(FileName, DwgVersion.Newest);
        trExport.Commit();
    }
}

// Dispose without commit, because the
// objects need to be in your original point
// at the end of the program.
trMoveToOrigin.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repositioning the objects created in the new drawing by the [`wblock`](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2019/ENU/?guid=OREFNET-Autodesk_AutoCAD_DatabaseServices_Database_Wblock) operation, I would suggest supplyng the [`wblock`](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2019/ENU/?guid=OREFNET-Autodesk_AutoCAD_DatabaseServices_Database_Wblock) method with a basepoint argument equal to the lower-left extent of the selection of objects - you are currently supplying the origin as the base point (`Point3d.Origin`).

For example, based on the code posted in your answer, you might try supplying the `minExPt` variable as the basepoint argument, e.g.:

```
db.Wblock(newDb, objIds, minExPt, DuplicateRecordCloning.Ignore);
```

This will result in the new objects being positioned with the lower-left corner of the rectangular extents at the origin of the new drawing.

Comment: Hi, @Lee Mac, thanks for your answer. I really enjoy your AutoLisp blog!
Well... I've tried to supply the _basepoint_ argument but this basepoint is only used when the objects exported are inserted as a block on another drawing, while in the new drawing created by wblock method the objects are placed at the same point from your origin drawing. Maybe, I'm missing something?

Comment: @WeiglasRibeiro Thank you for your positive feedback for my site! I've updated my answer - I hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: I posted [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56793567/7869240) showing what I tried with your informations

Answer (score 0):

@LeeMac, as I commented on your answer, I've tried to supply the `basepoint` argument to the `wblock` method, but it had no effects. The exported objects in the new drawing still on the same point the original objects are in the original drawing.

```
using(Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{
    // Get the extents points 
    // of the selected objects.
    var extPts = tr.GetExtents(objIdArray);
    var minExPt = extPts.MinPoint;

    // Create a new external database, where the
    // exported objects will be created.
    using (var newDb = new Database(true, false))
    {
        using (var trExport = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            db.Wblock(newDb, objIds, minExPt, DuplicateRecordCloning.Ignore);
            newDb.SaveAs(FileName, DwgVersion.Newest);
            trExport.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

[Image: Objects on original drawing selected to be exported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XE18.jpg)

[Image: Objects on new drawing still at the same point the original objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ukos.jpg)

And I realized this basepoint supllied to the wblock method is only used when the exported objects are inserted as a block in a drawing.

[Image: The minExPt supplied is only used whe the exported objects are inserted as a block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTQLW.jpg)

I tested the WBLOCK command too, and happens the same when I click on a basepoint.